# GeoPandas .explode() FutureWarning: Currently, index_parts defaults to True, but in the future, it will default to False to be consistent with Pandas

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas, indexing, explode

I have a simple [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) containing 2 records, with MultiPolygonZ having several single parts as geometry elements. When I try to split those in their single parts using the [`.explode()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html) method, it raises an obscure warning which I don't know how to interpret and what to do to be compliant with the future behaviour:

Here is a small, reproducible code snippet to help you get your hands on this problem:

```py
import geopandas as gpd # version: '0.12.2'
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

mp1 = MultiPolygon([
    Polygon(((0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (0,0))),
    Polygon(((10,10), (10,11), (11,11), (11,10), (10,10)))
])
mp2 = MultiPolygon([
    Polygon(((15,15), (15,16), (16,16), (16,15))),
    Polygon(((20,20), (20,22), (22,22), (22,20)))
])

d = {'names': ['name1', 'name2'], 'geometry': [mp1, mp2,]}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d)

gdf.explode()

/tmp/ipykernel_2843848/1394716190.py:1:
  FutureWarning: Currently, index_parts defaults to True,
  but in the future, it will default to False to be consistent with Pandas.
  Use `index_parts=True` to keep the current behavior and True/False
  to silence the warning.
    gdf.explode()

>:
     names                                 geometry
0 0  name1  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1...
  1  name1  POLYGON ((10.00000 10.00000, 10.0000...
1 0  name2  POLYGON ((15.00000 15.00000, 15.0000...
  1  name2  POLYGON ((20.00000 20.00000, 20.0000...
```

Is there something I can do to "fix" that, i.e what could be the correct syntax?

The current version of geopandas that I'm using is `'0.12.2'` and pandas is: `'1.5.2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html) now will create a sublevel index to organize a multipart exploded object, to do this, if you want, just add the parameter 'index_parts=True' inside the explode calls:

```py
import geopandas as gpd # version: '0.12.2'
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

mp1 = MultiPolygon([
    Polygon(((0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (0,0))),
    Polygon(((10,10), (10,11), (11,11), (11,10), (10,10)))
])
mp2 = MultiPolygon([
    Polygon(((15,15), (15,16), (16,16), (16,15))),
    Polygon(((20,20), (20,22), (22,22), (22,20)))
])

d = {'names': ['name1', 'name2'], 'geometry': [mp1, mp2,]}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d)
    
gdf.explode(index_parts=True)

>: 
     names                                 geometry
0 0  name1  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1...
  1  name1  POLYGON ((10.00000 10.00000, 10.0000...
1 0  name2  POLYGON ((15.00000 15.00000, 15.0000...
  1  name2  POLYGON ((20.00000 20.00000, 20.0000...
```

Just to spot the differences, here's what you get with `index_parts=False`, which will be the future behaviour:

```py
gdf.explode(index_parts=False)

>: 
   names                                 geometry
0  name1  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1...
0  name1  POLYGON ((10.00000 10.00000, 10.0000...
1  name2  POLYGON ((15.00000 15.00000, 15.0000...
1  name2  POLYGON ((20.00000 20.00000, 20.0000...
```

Notice that the indices will then no more be unique. But you can still reindex it if needed:

```py
gdf_exploded = gdf.explode(index_parts=False)
gdf_exploded.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

gdf_exploded
>: 
   names                                 geometry
0  name1  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1...
1  name1  POLYGON ((10.00000 10.00000, 10.0000...
2  name2  POLYGON ((15.00000 15.00000, 15.0000...
3  name2  POLYGON ((20.00000 20.00000, 20.0000...
```

Comment: Clear enough, thanks. I've added an example of the future behaviour for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, here is the source code from where the warning is issued and where the actual behaviour is defined in the `.explode()` method in the `GeoDataFrame` class:

```py
def explode(self, column=None, ignore_index=False, index_parts=None, **kwargs):
    
    (...)
    
    if index_parts is None:
        if not ignore_index:
            warnings.warn(
                "Currently, index_parts defaults to True, but in the future, "
                "it will default to False to be consistent with Pandas. "
                "Use `index_parts=True` to keep the current behavior and "
                "True/False to silence the warning.",
                FutureWarning,
                stacklevel=2,
            )
        index_parts = True
```

Source: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/7e1164fff8d85ef48f857c10a648188b3692b56e/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L1819-L1829